# Future is halting rest of program execution

Tags: java, multithreading, future, executorservice

I am trying to execute 2 jobs parallel from main thread but if a callback method take long time to give response rest of requests are pause and wait to complete first.

Here is my code:

```
 private final ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);

 private void executeService(String uuid) {
    System.out.println("query executed done: " + uuid);
} 

 private String getAsynchTest(final String uuid) throws Exception {
    testAsynchF = executorService.submit(
            new Callable<String>() {
                public String call() throws Exception {
                    executeService(uuid);
                    return getFutuerResult(uuid, Thread.currentThread()); // long processing
                }
            });
    return testAsynchF.get();
}

public String getFutuerResult(String uuid, Thread t) {
    String dummy = "your result for request: "+uuid;
     if (uuid.equalsIgnoreCase("112")) {
        try {
            t.join();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return dummy;
}

 public static void main(String[] args) {
    SynchronousTimeoutTester tester = new SynchronousTimeoutTester();

    try {
        String one = "112"
        System.out.println("Result sync call:*** " + tester.getAsynchTest(one));

        String two = "115";
        System.out.println("Result sync call:**** " + tester.getAsynchTest(two));

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("catched as Exception: " + e);
    }

 }
```

Why is this stopping to execute request 115 if request 112 thread is pause?

Comment: this doesn't compile... specifically what is the implementation of `executeService(String)` and `getFutureResult(String)`?

Comment: executeService method is not listed, getFutuerResult expects a Thread argument, there is a line missing a semicolon in main

Comment: tester.shutdown() also not specified

Comment: Remove that shutdown method call.. question updated

Answer (score 0):

Since you pass `Thread.currentThread()` to `getFutureResult` and that method calls `join()` on its thread argument (in case uuid is "112"), the method will wait for its own thread to end, which it can't since it's waiting.

Comment: ok. Can you please tell me one thing if i want to pause request 112 for testing and allow request 115 to continue then where should i add this join ?

Comment: If you want to perform several jobs concurrently, but do not care about the order of results, and want to process the results as they come in, I suggest you look into `CompletionService`s.

Comment: ok. Can you give me hint how i can sleep thread of any request(ex=112) in callback method ?